# Stuck in App DB model structure in Django. (Job safety checklist App)

Tags: python, django, database, web, model

I want to create an App which is more like a checklist app which will have multiple questions (like a polls) like below but more than one.

in response there will be 3 choices, Yes, No, and NA.

for e.g.

- Q.1. Is BA staff equipped with Protective equipments?
- Ans. i.) Yes , ii.) No , iii) N/A
- Q.2. Weather is in good condition to climb to Work?
- Ans. i.) Yes , ii.) No , iii.) N/A

Like this there will be a checklist with about 7-8 similar questions.

and for each logged in user a seperate instance for complete checklist will be saved.

My solution (not scalable):

To create a model like.

class Checklist:

```
qus1 = model.CharField(...choices = yesnochoices)

qus2 = model.CharField(...choices = yesnochoices)
```

and so on. but this won't be good as professional and much scalable.

Could you please suggest how should i made this. other than the approach like above?

Comment: Make an extra model `ChecklistQuestion` that refers to the `Checklist` and thus results in a many-to-one relation.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem correctly, you can do something like this:
you can have a Question model. and then an Answer model which connects users to the questions.
which would be something like this:

```
class Question(models.Model):
    text = models.CharField()

class Answer(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    answer = models.CharField(choices=yesnochoices)
```

I think something like this is quite scalable and will solve your problem.

Comment: Nice suggestion, i will try by modifying it further more.